# Capacitance of plate or Rectangular prism

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, capacitance

I am trying to calculate the capacitance of a rectangular prism. This would be the self capacitance with reference to infinity. If that is a tough Job, I could settle for approximating the capacitance of a rectangle to infinity.

Surprisingly, I cannot seem to find papers or much information about it.

Comment: The question is what is the potential at surface of the rectangular prism.

Comment: Okay, makes sense, but can you maybe elaborate on that?